# Product Export Show Error

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, export

How to download csv in my local system....?

**controller.php**

```
public function exportmeAction(){
      try{
        $products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('category_ids');
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//optional for only enabled products
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
        ->joinField('qty',
                         'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                         'qty',
                         'product_id=entity_id',
                         '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                         'left');;//optional for products only visible in catalog and search
        $fp = fopen('exports.csv', 'w');
        $csvHeader = array("Product Id","Product Name","Product Sku","Product Url", "Product Image Url","Category Ids","Description","Product Qty","Special Price", "Price");
        fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,",");
        foreach ($products as $product){
            echo $sku = $product->getSku();
            echo $name = $product->getName();
            echo $id = $product->getId();
            echo $url = $product->getProductUrl();
            echo $des = $product->getDescription();
            echo $splprice = (int)$product->getFinalPrice();
            echo $price = (int)$product->getPrice();
            echo $qty = (int)$product->getQty();
            echo $img = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image');
            echo $categoryIds = implode('|', $product->getCategoryIds());//change the category separator if needed
            fputcsv($fp, array($id, $name, $sku, $url, $img,$categoryIds,$des,$qty,$splprice,$price), ",");
        }
        fclose($fp);
      }

       catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Error Message: '.$e->getMessage();
      }
      $this->_redirectReferer();
      Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess("Done");
   }
```

**phtml**

```
<form class="my-form" name="myForm" id="customize" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('productexport/index/exportme');?>" method="post">

<div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Customize" class="btn btn-default" /></div> 
</form>
```

i got this error

```
Cannot send headers; headers already sent in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\code\local\MPS\Productexport\controllers\IndexController.php, line 48
```

Also i want to download in my local system how to achieve this?

Comment: remove echo with in for each loop and why you are not using magento built in function to create a csv and download it

Comment: I want to download my local system. I don't want to all field. I want to custom

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Magento functions and change it as you want use below code

```
public function exportmeAction()
{

    $productCount = 0;
    try {
        //configure the collection filters.
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        //Add a page size to the result set.
        $collection->setPageSize(100);
        //discover how many page the result will be.
        $pages = $collection->getLastPageNumber();
        $currentPage = 1;
        //This is the file to append the output to.
        $io = new Varien_Io_File();
        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'export' . DS;
        $name = 'your_file_name';
        $file = $path . DS . $name . '.csv';
        $io->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
        $io->open(array('path' => $path));
        $io->streamOpen($file, 'w+');
        $io->streamLock(true);
        $csvHeader = array("Product Id", "Product Name", "Product Sku", "Product Url", "Product Image Url", "Category Ids", "Description", "Product Qty", "Special Price", "Price");
        $io->streamWriteCsv($csvHeader);
        $productArray = array();
        do {
            //Tell the collection which page to load.
            $collection->setCurPage($currentPage);
            $collection->load();
            foreach ($collection as $product) {
                //write the collection array as a CSV.
                unset($productArray);
                $sku = $product->getSku();
                $name = $product->getName();
                $id = $product->getId();
                $url = $product->getProductUrl();
                $des = $product->getDescription();
                $splprice = (int)$product->getFinalPrice();
                $price = (int)$product->getPrice();
                $qty = (int)$product->getQty();
                $img = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image');
                $categoryIds = implode('|', $product->getCategoryIds());//change the category separator if needed

                $productArray = array($id, $name, $sku, $url, $img,$categoryIds,$des,$qty,$splprice,$price);
                $io->streamWriteCsv($productArray);

                $productCount++;
            }
            $currentPage++;
            //make the collection unload the data in memory so it will pick up the next page when load() is called.
            $collection->clear();
        } while ($currentPage <= $pages);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //$response['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        Mage::printException($e);
    }
    $file_array = array(
        'type'  => 'filename',
        'value' => $file,
        'rm'    => true // can delete file after use
    );
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse("product_exp.csv", $file_array);

    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess("Done");

}
```

put name of your csv file in $name and check your var/export folder

Comment: hey i want to download in my local machine not on server folder

Comment: check edited answer

Comment: Still save only var/export folder also format is changed means all value arranged in same cell

Comment: please check updated answer i test this function and i am able to download the file and the format is ok now

Comment: Hey Now Download in my local system but no data in that csv

Comment: remove this line from function $collection->getSelect()->limit(100); and do you have any product data?

Comment: product_exp.csv in this file no data but this file your_file_name.csv have a data

Comment: did you updated your code? please check my answer now

Comment: Ya Still same no data in local dpwnload file

Comment: when you put this in code it removes the file after download $file_array = array(
        'type'  => 'filename',
        'value' => $file,
        'rm'    => true // can delete file after use
    );

Comment: Hey Sorry i am not getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52779/discussion-between-shaheer-ali-and-kothari).

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is caused by the fact that you're using `echo` in your controller.

Here's an updated version of your code that will let you download the CSV locally

```
public function exportmeAction(){
      try{
        $products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('category_ids');
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//optional for only enabled products
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
        ->joinField('qty',
                         'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                         'qty',
                         'product_id=entity_id',
                         '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                         'left');;//optional for products only visible in catalog and search
        $content = '"Product Id","Product Name","Product Sku","Product Url", "Product Image Url","Category Ids","Description","Product Qty","Special Price", "Price"\n';
        foreach ($products as $product){
            $content .= $product->getSku() . ",";
            $content .= $product->getName() . ",";
            $content .= $product->getId() . ",";
            $content .= $product->getProductUrl() . ",";
            $content .= $product->getDescription() . ",";
            $content .= (int)$product->getFinalPrice() . ",";
            $content .= (int)$product->getPrice() . ",";
            $content .= (int)$product->getQty() . ",";
            $content .= (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image') . ",";
            $content .= implode('|', $product->getCategoryIds()) . ",";//change the category separator if needed
            $content .= "\n";
        }
      }

       catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Error Message: '.$e->getMessage();
      }
      Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess("Done");
      $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('export.csv', $content, 'text/csv');
   }
```

Comment: all content showing single column only

Comment: @Kothari try to set the delimiter as a comma and that'll work ;)

Comment: how i can set delimiter as a comma

Answer (score 0):

this is the sctipt code to export all product it will helpful for you.

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$data=array();
$data['entity'] = 'catalog_product';
$data['file_format'] = 'csv';
$data['form_key'] =Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); 
$data['export_filter']=array();

$model = Mage::getModel('importexport/export');
$model->setData($data);

$model->export();
$model->getContentType();

?>
```